# How to align dates for merging two xts files?

Tags: r, merge, xts, apply

I'm trying to analyze 1-year %-change data in R on two data series by merging them into one file. One series is weekly and the other is monthly. Converting the weekly series to monthly is the problem. Using `apply.monthly()` on the weekly data creates a monthly file but with intra-monthly dates that don't match the first-day-of-month format in the monthly series after combining the two files via `merge.xts()`. Question: How to change the resulting merged file (sample below) to one monthly entry for both series?

```
2012-11-01 0.02079801          NA
2012-11-24         NA -0.03375796
2012-12-01 0.02052502          NA
2012-12-29         NA  0.04442094
2013-01-01 0.01881466          NA
2013-01-26         NA  0.06370272
2013-02-01 0.01859883          NA
2013-02-23         NA  0.02999318
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass `indexAt="firstof"` in a call to `to.monthly` to get monthly data using the first of the month for the index.

```
library(quantmod) 
getSymbols(c("USPRIV", "ICSA"), src="FRED")
merge(USPRIV, to.monthly(ICSA, indexAt="firstof", OHLC=FALSE))
```

Comment: GSee, that's it. Thank you so much. I can use this with a few tweaks. Success!

Comment: @JPP: if this best answered you question, please consider ticking the green check mark next to it.

Comment: This fix doesn't seem to work with later packages and/or versions of R. Any thoughts? All is well with R 2.14.1 and R Studio 0.97.332 and xts 0.8-6. Later versions of one or more of these (I think it's xts) render the fix inoperable. Ugh!!?!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
do.call(rbind, by(d[-1], d[[1]] - as.POSIXlt(d[[1]])$mday, FUN=apply, 2, sum, na.rm=TRUE))
##                    V2          V3
## 2012-10-31 0.02079801 -0.03375796
## 2012-11-30 0.02052502  0.04442094
## 2012-12-31 0.01881466  0.06370272
## 2013-01-31 0.01859883  0.02999318
```

Note that the dates are encoded as row names, not as a column in the result.

Comment: Thanks so much, but my apologies for asking further: Would I run this on only the weekly data set? Or both series? Does the "d" represent the series?

Comment: `d` represents a data.frame built from what you have pasted above.  However, you could use a very similar expression to aggregate the weekly data.  Seeing an example of (a subset of) the original data would help in writing that code.

Comment: Much appreciated. Here's what I did. The monthly series is private payrolls (USPRIV), the weekly series is jobless claims (ICSA). First, aggregate weekly to monthly, then create 1yr % changes on both:                                                               ICSA <-aggregate(ICSA, as.yearmon(time(ICSA)), mean)

Comment: USPRIV
2012-09-01 112120
2012-10-01 112337
2012-11-01 112593
2012-12-01 112817
2013-01-01 112957
2013-02-01 113203 ICSA
2013-02-09 342000
2013-02-16 366000
2013-02-23 347000
2013-03-02 342000
2013-03-09 334000
2013-03-16 336000

Comment: @JPP It's not very usable in that format (just one line in the comment).  Best to edit your question instead.

Comment: Sorry. Is there any way to aggregate the weekly data to monthly, and then reformat the data so that its date ID is first day of month? Or perhaps there's a monthly aggregation tool that offers this option?

Comment: It is possible.  For example, if you have a `Date` object `x`, `x - as.POSIXlt(x)$mday + 1` is the first day of the month.  That may be what you want in your weekly aggregation.

Comment: I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:                       <blockquote<y <-aggregate(x, as.yearmon(time(x - as.POSIXlt(x)$mday +1)), mean)</blockquote>                                                  I'm obviously mucking this up somewhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: y <-aggregate(x, as.yearmon(time(x - as.POSIXlt(x)$mday - 1)), mean)

Answer (score 0):

It is a frequently occurring  issue. And sometimes I forget my own solution for it and google does not easily lead to one. So I am posting my solution here.

Basically, just convert the index of monthly aggregated series to `yearmon`. You can also optionally convert it back to `yyyy-mm-dd` (to 1st of each month ) format with `as.date` . After the exact dates are stripped and the indices are 'homogenised' , all the columns align perfectly.

```
# Here with dplyr 
time(myxts)<- time(myxts) %>% as.yearmon() %%> as.date()
#or without dplyr
time(myxts)<-  as.date( as.yearmon( time(myxts) )  )
```